# Extract day/year from dataframe string column and sum it [Python]

Tags: python

I have a column in a dataframe called "time" that has a string format. I would like to extract the year and day digit from the string of each cell of that column, create a new column where year digit is multiplied by 365 and if day digit available is added as per the below calculation. Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most efficient or robust solution. Here is a function that can take in one of your strings from the `time` column and return the `output` value

```
def foo(s):
    result = 0
    l = s.split()
    for i, word in enumerate(l):
        if not word.isdigit():
            continue
        # word is number
        if l[i+1] == 'year':  # unit is years
            result += int(word) * 365
        else:  # unit is days
            result += int(word)
    return result

print(foo('5 day'))  # 5
print(foo('2 year'))  # 730
print(foo('3 year 10 day'))  # 1105
```

Or if you prefer a one-liner

```
def foo(s):
    return sum(int(word) * (365 if s.split()[i+1] == 'year' else 1) for i, word in enumerate(s.split()) if word.isdigit())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

One way to do it is [this.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/05_add_columns.html)

Another way would be to split the "Time" into several columns [like this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-a-text-column-into-two-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/)